# Render a Projection of specific size and position onto another

Tags: c#, .net, directx, directx-11, sharpdx

I am trying to Render a 3D-View onto another on a specified Position and Size.
And because I can not explain it exactly, I made a graphic.

[Graphic-Description of my Problem](http://picload.org/view/oiwaapc/problem.png.html)

If you could help me out, could you please also tell me how to call the case I am searching for so I can do some more research on it?

Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in several ways:

- Create alternative [viewport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(s) and [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it before rendering each your Picture-in-picture stuff
- [Render to texture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then just draw it as textured quad (sprite)
- Many [cheat-tricks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Compositing) with a [stencil buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_buffer)

  (links above go to native functions, but I hope you can figure out ones for your framework)

Maybe I've forget something else.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! The word "Viewport" and your Resources helped me out very well!